# MappingException with Doctrine ORM - Class does not exist

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine 2.6.2 in my PHP project. The Schema was created successfully with the ORM-Tool, but on runtime, a MappingException is thrown.

I still cannot make sense out of the Exception Error message "Class 'credentials' does not exist in ..." because I don't know about doctrines internals.

my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.6.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

I tried to change some phpdoc annotations and reset the schema multiple times.

Does someone has experienced similar issues with doctrine? I'd love some hint about this, because I'm not even sure if this problem is caused by my PHP code files or maybe by some misconfiguration of the orm tool I'm using, or most probably by something I didn't think of yet.

```php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="credentials")
 */
class Credentials
{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $Email;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $Loginname;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $EntropyString;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $AccessToken;


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

Here is the full Response from apache:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Class
>   'credentials' does not exist in
>   F:\XAMPP\httpd.private\src\php\vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:93
>   Stack trace: #0
>   F:\XAMPP\httpd.private\src\php\vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService.php(24):
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('credentials')
>
> ## 1 F:\XAMPP\httpd.private\src\php\vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(250):
>
> Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses('credentials')
>
> ## 2 F:\XAMPP\httpd.private\src\php\vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(283):
>
> Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses('credentials')
>
> ## 3 F:\XAMPP\httpd.private\src\php\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadat
>
> in
>   F:\XAMPP\httpd.private\src\php\vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php
>   on line 93

the error occurs on a call to EntityManager's Find method:

```php
$this->credentials = $this->entityManager->Find('credentials', $result[0]["id"]);
```

Comment: can you show the filename where your class is declared?

Comment: the filename is "credentials.php"

Comment: do it with upletter - Credentials.php :)

Comment: i did try again after changing the filename to "Credentials.php". -> same MappingException.

Comment: do you use some framework?

Comment: i use doctrine and symfony.

Comment: so, clear the cache after you set correct filename - Credentials.php can you please provide doctrine.yaml if it won't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195696/discussion-between-bobbey-and-myxaxa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exception does not occur anymore after adding the fully qualified class name to the call on EntityManager's Find method:

```php
$this->credentials = $this->entityManager->Find('Businessrelations\Database\Credentials', $result[0]["id"]);
```